# Which is better in accessing a property value?

Tags: c#

Which is better in accessing a property value?

Accessing like this

```
propertyobjA.objB.Prop1
propertyobjA.objB.Prop2
```

or assign to var

```
var objB = propertyobjA.objB;
then call objB.Prop1 and objB.Prop1
```

Which one improves performance in c#?

Comment: The usual method is time each case and see which is faster. Also, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: The way to find out is to test both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impact to performance largely depends on the *implementation* of the `propertyObjA.objB` property getter. For instance, if it is simply implemented as:

```
public Foo objB { get { return this._objB; } }
```

Then calling that twice will have a negligible impact on performance.

If, however, that same property did something computationally expensive, then your second suggestion would perform better.

That being said, the framework guidelines state that you should not use property getters to hide potentially computationally expensive operations, instead preferring a method call instead, e.g.:

```
public objB ComputeB ();
```

Answer (score 4):

To be perfectly the honest, the answer is likely that the second will be faster, but I can pretty much guarantee that *it will not matter in the slightest*. You should be careful of thinking too hard about optimisation too early. 99% of all performance issues are down to much larger issues such as hitting a database too frequently, etc., not trivial issues like this. Even if there was a tiny difference between the two cases, unless this is some of the most time-critical software on the planet, what matters is readability (not that either are hard to read in this case), not which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what objB is. If you are calculating something (which you *shouldn't* do but *can* do) then of course assigning it to a value will yield better performance.

Another note, you should avoid having dependencies on sub properties of a variable, since you are putting a higher coupling between the classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this won't make a big difference performancewise (second alternative might be a bit faster). But this is not the place where your performance problems (if any) come from.

**UPDATE**: Thinking about, the value of `propertyobjA.objB` could change between getting `Prop1` and `Prop2`, so the two alternatives cannot be considered as being the same code.

Comment: +1. One thing is for sure; the compiler is *much better* at this kind of micro-optimisation than the vast majority of programmers. In modern languages like C#, you definitely won't know what exactly your code translates in to after the compiler is done with it.

Comment: @Thor84no Updated my answer, just noticed that the two samples are not equivalent code.

Comment: That would depend on whether the properties are constants or not. Presumably he has enough control over the code that that shouldn't be a concern either way.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to not concern yourself with things like that when writing  code in a higher level language such as c#.

Modern compilers of such languages as c# and java are extremely sofisticated and will perform all kinds optimizations on your code. The end result for you as developer is that you will never see a difference in performance when writing a particular trivial piece of code one way or the other. The compiler will pick the most optimal way.

Everything else is down to preference. If you like to chain several property accesses, that's fine. If you like to assign an intermediate result to a variable to improve readability of your code, that's fine too.